# Xamarin Forms, add components in runtime (MVVM)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to recreate the behavior that in WPF I obtained with **ItemsControl**, that is the possibility to create objects (entries, pickers, labels) at runtime starting from a list of objects in ViewModel.

In my specific case I have to read from a csv of configuration of the app the fields that I will have to present to the user eaven of mixed type (text, date, etc)

Is it possible to do it in **Xamarin Froms**? What workaround or alternatives are there?

Comment: Yes.  `var label = new Label();`. I'm not familiar with `ItemsControl` so I don't know exactly what functionality it provides for you, but you can certainly create controls dynamically with Forms.

Comment: In a "code behind" way "var label = new Label() MyCont.Children.Add (label)" is what I do but I don't know how to do it in MVVM without the View Model knowing something about the view

Comment: Yes, you can. You have to use Binding in your View and your ViewModel have to inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged (System.ComponentModel) after initializing your object just do a page.BindingContext = viewModel;before showing them. There maybe a framework available do manage that

Answer (score 0):

Create a class of a book and then create an ObservableCollection from it.
Assign it to the ItemsSource property in ListView.
Inside the DataTemplate, place and configure your card

For example
XAMl

```
<ContentPage>
  <ListView  
                   ItemsSource="{Binding BookInfo}"
                   ItemSize="100">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.4*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.6*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Text="{Binding BookName}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Teal" FontSize="21" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding BookDescription}" TextColor="Teal" FontSize="15"/>
        </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

c#

```
public class BookInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string bookName;
    private string bookDesc;

    public string BookName
    {
        get { return bookName; }
        set
        {
            bookName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BookName");
        }
    }

    public string BookDescription
    {
        get { return bookDesc; }
        set
        {
            bookDesc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BookDescription");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
           this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

public class BookInfoRepository
{
private ObservableCollection bookInfo;

```
public ObservableCollection<BookInfo> BookInfo
{
    get { return bookInfo; }
    set { this.bookInfo = value; }
}

public BookInfoRepository()
{
    GenerateBookInfo();
}

internal void GenerateBookInfo()
{
    bookInfo = new ObservableCollection<BookInfo>();
    bookInfo.Add(new BookInfo() { BookName = "Object-Oriented Programming in C#", BookDescription = "Object-oriented programming is a programming paradigm based on the concept of objects" });
    bookInfo.Add(new BookInfo() { BookName = "C# Code Contracts", BookDescription = "Code Contracts provide a way to convey code assumptions" });
    bookInfo.Add(new BookInfo() { BookName = "Machine Learning Using C#", BookDescription = "You’ll learn several different approaches to applying machine learning" });
    bookInfo.Add(new BookInfo() { BookName = "Neural Networks Using C#", BookDescription = "Neural networks are an exciting field of software development" });
    bookInfo.Add(new BookInfo() { BookName = "Visual Studio Code", BookDescription = "It is a powerful tool for editing code and serves for end-to-end programming" });
    bookInfo.Add(new BookInfo() { BookName = "Android Programming", BookDescription = "It is provides a useful overview of the Android application life cycle" });
    bookInfo.Add(new BookInfo() { BookName = "iOS Succinctly", BookDescription = "It is for developers looking to step into frightening world of iPhone" });
    bookInfo.Add(new BookInfo() { BookName = "Visual Studio 2015", BookDescription = "The new version of the widely-used integrated development environment" });
    bookInfo.Add(new BookInfo() { BookName = "Xamarin.Forms", BookDescription = "Its creates mappings from its C# classes and controls directly" });
    bookInfo.Add(new BookInfo() { BookName = "Windows Store Apps", BookDescription = "Windows Store apps present a radical shift in Windows development" });
}
```

}